# segmentation fault(core dumped) in python with swig, but it works when I change the variable name

Tags: python, c++, variables, segmentation-fault, swig

I'm using python with swig.
The cpp file contains a variable `int step=0;`
and a function use the variable `void test();`
I get a segmentation fault when I call the function in python.
But after I change the variable name to `step2`, it works.

Version:
swig 4.0.0
python 3.6.7

This get a segmentation fault:

1.ex.cpp

```
#include<iostream>

int step = 0;

void test(){
    step += 1;
    printf("ok\n");
}
```

2.ex.i

```
%module ex

%inline %{
    extern void test();
%}
```

3.run

```
swig -c++ -python ex.i
g++ -fPIC -c ex.cpp -c ex_wrap.cxx -I/home/lzhang/venv/include/python3.6m
g++ -shared ex.o ex_wrap.o -o _ex.so
```

4.get a segmentation fault

```
$ python
Python 3.6.7 (default, Oct 22 2018, 11:32:17) 
[GCC 8.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import ex
>>> ex.test()
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

But I only change variable name:

```
#include<iostream>

int step2 = 0;

void test(){
    step2 += 1;
    printf("ok\n");
}
```

After recompile, it works.

```
$ python
Python 3.6.7 (default, Oct 22 2018, 11:32:17) 
[GCC 8.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import ex
>>> ex.test()
ok
>>>
```

How can I avoid this kind of error?

Comment: You have some undefined behaviour here, but it's almost impossible to say what from the code you've shown. Can you show the *minimal* but still complete code that we can use to run, investigate and understand the situation for ourselves? You're unlikely to get an answer without that. At a best guess I'd sprinkle some asserts around your code, to check that all your array indexing is within bounds, e.g. `assert(sno < state && pno < pn);` etc.before you read or write to any array.

Comment: @Flexo I added the minimal complete code

Comment: Please post the **actual code**. *ex.cpp* does not build because *printf* is unknown. Also what's with the *-I...* when compiling?

Comment: @CristiFati I think this is real code - often printf 'works' without `#include <stdio.h>` and I can repro this on my test setup as-is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The root of your problem seems to be that `step` is exported from libc, at least on a bunch of common systems, so you've got a global namespace colision.

```
nm -D /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc-2.28.so|grep step
000c5210 W step
```

(It's a function, I was a bit curious about what it's for since it's not one I'm familiar with - turns out it's something to do with regex processing and finding the next match of a compiled regex in a string buffer)

The simplest solution to this in your specific example is to make your global variable `step` be `static` (or use an anonymous namespace) instead:

```
#include<iostream>

static int step = 0;

void test(){
    step += 1;
    printf("ok\n");
}
```

This is sufficient to fix your example.

It's good practice to make sure all global variables are static unless you really want to be exporting them, particularly so when building a shared object (e.g. a Python module).

You can also use gcc's `-fvisibility=hidden` to default to hiding rather than exporting global variables. (SWIG correctly makes sure things which need to be exported are still visible even when this is set).